# Web service that provides official movie art and screenshots

Tags: web-services

Is there any Web-service that provides official movie art or movie screenshots?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I'm not sure as to a cost associated with either of the following APIs, and I am not affiliated with either group/organization/company.

It appears that Rotten Tomatoes offers an API which can fetch movie posters:
http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs

The Movie Database API may also be an option; it looks like it can get posters and backdrops for an ID (which can be searched for in the API as well):
http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fmovie%2F%7Bid%7D%2Fimages

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Netflix oData service: http://developer.netflix.com/docs/oData_Catalog